# Machine Learning Error - 'ValueError: Shapes (100, 10) and (100, 5) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 1)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science, bigdata

I'm encountering an error while working on a machine learning project. I have a dataset with 100 samples and 10 features, and I'm trying to train a model using a neural network. However, when I run my code, I receive the following error message:

ValueError: Shapes (100, 10) and (100, 5) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 1)

I'm unsure why this error is occurring. Could someone please help me understand what's causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

# Assuming 'X' is my input data with shape (100, 10)
X = np.random.random((100, 10))
# Assuming 'y' is my target data with shape (100, 1)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_shape=(10,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check again, because I ran your code and it works fine. However, I recommend you for next projects that define input_shape attribute in base of input set's shape, not a constant.